# What's the name of the fallacy when you use a worst situation to ignore the current?

Tags: fallacies

For example, I'm hungry, but the Africa kids are much more (so I should not care about my hungry).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me the above example sounds like being related to the category of fallacies that arise due to missing the point. Fallacies of this category include strawman,  Non Sequitur, Ignoratio Elenchi and red herring.

Among these, red herring fits the description best. The fallacy occurs when an irrelevant subject is interjected into the conversation to divert attentions away from the main issue. More specifically, in offering an argument toward a certain topic, the arguer changes the topic and provides evidence that is irrelevant to the original topic, and then draws a conclusion about the original topic through the distraction. This is an example:

`I believe that Yahoo is a better search engine than Google or Bing. Yahoo hired a female CEO, which shows its commitment to the gender equality issue in tech industry. By contrast, Google and Microsoft, the owner of Bing, had done nothing to mitigate the inequality problem. Clearly, Yahoo is the winner in the field of search engine technology.`

The fallacy gets its name from the practice of training a hunting dog. A red herring, a fish with very strong scent, is dragged across the trail with the aim of leading dogs astray. Only the best dogs will follow the original scent.